# Is it safe in React 18+ to use ref.current as a dependency of useEffect when there is certainty the effect will run following a re-render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Premises:

- I am aware updating a ref (defined via `const myref = useRef()`) won't trigger a component re-render per-se
- I am also aware there is a [eslint rule](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) that recommends not to use `myRef.current` or omitting a given dependency in the effect
- I am aware I could use a `ref callback` but the ref I am using needs to be inside a hook, it doesn't depend on the DOM at all
- Using multiple effects is an option I have considered but it leads to race conditions as they both work on the same state in my use case (one write a new state, the other reads the OLD not-yet updated state)

Use case:
`myRef` keeps track of a state without having `state` as a direct dependency to avoid race conditions for the same reason explained above, while allowing for running this hook automatically any time setState is called externally from the hook.

The way this hook is designed, it is itself guaranteed to re-run because of state (eg `value`) or setState (called from outside the hook) other than the ref itself updates. I could confirm `the first effect re-runs` in React v18 when the ref changes without causing other apparent issues.

```
const [ state, setState ] = useState({})
const stateRef = useRef(state)
const [ value, setValue ] = useState(false)

const myHook = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
      if (!value) {
         // Compute and store the state: setState(computedState), then setValue(true)
      } else {
      // On a separate render cycle (ie when `value` becomes true), read the state from myRef.current (synced from `state` in the second effect), and do something else with it. At this point (the 2nd time the effect runs ) state is not yet updated 
      }
   }, [ value, stateRef.current] )

   useEffect(() => {
      useRef.current = state
   }, [state])

return [state, setState]
}
```

Question: given the provided scenario, is there any real risk in using `myRef.current` as a dependency?

Comment: The way you are describing it the `stateRef` does not seem to serve any purpose that can't be achieved by using `state` directly.

Comment: @apokryfos my example is a simplified version of the race condition (which is fundamentally "the state is not updated in time before being read again by either the same - or a separate - effect". What you say could as well be but my question didn't concern the why, but rather the risks involved in the technical approach.

Comment: Ok I see the concern now. There may be an issue if: value changes to `false` > a new state is computed and `setState` is called > the effect runs and updates `useRef.current` and the other effect runs again without `value` having changed. I think not having `useRef.current` in the deps at all is actually safer, though you might be able to bypass the need for all of this with a `useMemo` for the state rather than a `useState`

Comment: @apokryfos I would be curious to see an example you would use useMemo in the scenario :) As far as I know if no dependencies change, the effect won't run. and same for useMemo with its own dependencies, so I am not entirely sure what you mean exactly

Comment: To me it looks like `myHook` in its entirety can be replaced with a `useMemo` wherever its used. The issue with this approach is if `stateRef.current` changes but `value` does not and is `false` at the time when the effect runs you will end-up double computing state